# Embedding a file into Excel through VBA damages the file

Tags: excel, vba, embed

I have the following code

```
Private Sub btnOpenTemplate_Click()

Dim c As Range
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog, directory As String, fileName As String

Set c = Settings.Range("A1")
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Âûáåðèòå øàáëîí ÏÌÈ."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Word 2003", "*.doc?"

    If .Show = True Then
      fileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
If fileName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Dir(fileName, vbNormal) <> "" Then
    If c.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then
        c.Worksheet.OLEObjects(1).Delete
    End If
    Settings.OLEObjects.Add fileName:=fileName, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True
End If

Settings.Range("A2").Value = fileName
lblTemplateFile.Caption = fileName

End Sub
```

Whenever it is executed, the workbook gets damaged and Excel is unable to repair and save it. What could be wrong? What I mean is that the workbook works fine just until I embed an object (Word doc) into it via the macro. Then it gets damaged.

Comment: Embedded OLE objects have a tendency to corrupt things... does it work correctly if you embed it manually? What version of Excel are you embedding a Word 97-2003 document into?

Comment: Unrelated, but why do `c.Worksheet.OLEObjects` instead of `Settings.OLEObjects`?

Comment: My fail, it remained after my prior test code. When I insert the same file manually, it works fine. It is Excel 2013.